# Accessing image upload form without clicking form on React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to add a hidden image upload form to my page, that I'll later open with a function (Rather than clicking the form directly).

This is what I'm trying to do, but it says "cannot read properties of null, reading click."

What's the right way to do this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SimpleForm from "./components/chatbot/SimpleForm";
var img_upload_form = document.getElementById('imgupload')

function selectImageUpload() {
  img_upload_form.click()
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <SimpleForm />
      <input type="file" id="imgupload" style="display:none"/>
      <button id="OpenImgUpload">Image Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
       
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happend because u want to get dom object before it's exist. id "imgupload" only exist after react create it. use createRef to get dom object instead

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
import SimpleForm from "./components/chatbot/SimpleForm";

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.myRef = createRef();
}
doUpload(){
  this.myRef.current.click()
}
componentDidMount(){
 //this.myRef.current.click()
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <SimpleForm doUpload={doUpload.bind(this)}/>
      <input ref={this.myRef} type="file" id="imgupload" style={{display:'none'}}/>
      <button id="OpenImgUpload">Image Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
       
}

export default App;
```

inside SimpleForm

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      this.doUpload = props.doUpload
    }
    render(){
      return (<button onClick={this.doUpload} id="OpenImgUpload">Image    Upload</button>)
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting "props not defined." Sorry I'm new to React, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: oh yeah add constructor(props)

Comment: Thanks! Though now I'm getting this error instead, which I wasn't before. Any ideas?

"react-dom.development.js:2960 
        
       Uncaught Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX."

Comment: edited it again. sorry copy pasted your code without realizing it

Comment: its like excatly what its says. style is alwys accept object on string!

Comment: Hey thanks so much, but now it's saying "this.myRef.click" is not a function. I copied your code exactly. Sorry that I'm new to React, I'm pretty comfortable with vanillaJS but this is literally the first project I've tried in React.

Comment: add this.myRef.current.click()

Comment: Thank you very much again. That works. The last question I have, if you don't mind. If I wanted to access that function from the SimpleForm component, do I need to export it? Or how can I do that?